# Tkinter application restart

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, restart

I have an application written in a class which I want to restart with a single button

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program.
    Note: this function does not return. Any cleanup action (like
    saving data) must be done before calling this function."""
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Hello World!").pack()
Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I was using this code which I found on a thread , but this just quits the program and does not restarts it

My code is too long but it contains a single class which contains all the functions for my applications

I want to restart the application so that all the widgets get destroyed

Comment: It is possible to restart a program, but what you wanted to achieve doesn't seem to require a restart. Can't you just put everything in say a `Toplevel` and destroy it when not needed?

Comment: Seems to work for me.